# How to provide balance to validator nodes after blockchain creation private blockchain POA

Tags: ether, private-blockchain, poa

I'm working with a private Ethereum blockchain PoA with three validator nodes. I have initially added three wallet addresses to get some free ethers. However, when I checked the balance of one of the node today, it's showing zero.

So, my question is, how can we provide free ethers to that account after the chain is created?

Note: Gas price of all transactions are zero, I'm only sending 100 ethers when new user registered with the system.

Comment: No you can't. You can only add balances to them in the chain configuration before you create the chain

Comment: A POA doesn't have block rewards, validator only profits from transactions fees. If gas price is zero then validators will not profit from validating blocks.

Comment: @Ismael, Okay, but is there any issue if I put gas price zero?

Comment: @Div I don't see any issue with zero gas prices. But unless there's some sort of verification some malicious user can flood the network with transactions with zero gas price.